# Python: Count number of occurrences of list items in a string

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

If I have the following list

```
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
```

and another list

```
words = ["happiness", "yellow"]
```

how do I count the number of vowels in each word, i.e. happiness = 3, yellow=2?

Comment: Break the problem into simpler ones ... How do you count the number of occurrences of ONE letter in a string ? Once you have that, then you can go through the list of letters, and add the result of this function.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service, and there are dozens of questions on counting vowels using Python here already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
>>> words = ["happiness", "yellow"]
>>> [sum(c in vowels for c in word) for word in words]
[3, 2]
```

If you want mapping between the words and occurences, use dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {word: sum(c in vowels for c in word) for word in words}
{'happiness': 3, 'yellow': 2}
```

Converting `vowels` to `set` will make it more effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [0]*len(words)                # Initializing the data list
for index, word in enumerate(words): # Iterating through the list of words
 for letter in list(word):
  if letter in vowels:               #checking if the letter is in vowels
   data[index] = data[index]+1
print data
```

data now contains number of vowels corresponding to the same index as the words list. Cheers! :)