# Check whether a password has at least two different special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, passwords

I want to validate user's passwords (a string) by checking, whether it has at least two different *special characters*.

- Special characters `` "!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ " ``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Count number of occurrences of list items in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524531/python-count-number-of-occurrences-of-list-items-in-a-string)

Comment: @Aurora0001 I have to check the presence of different special characters, so how should I keep a count of that?

Comment: Ah, you need to make sure that two **different** ones are present? You could probably use the second approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24524593/6650102) and check that two of the values are greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to get unique occurrences, `set` is very useful.  This code uses `set` to turn the password into a set of unique characters.  It then uses `sum` to count the number of times these unique characters are `in` the special list.

**Code:**

```
def unique_special_count(password):
    # provide a list of special characters
    special = '''!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ '''

    # turn the password into a set of unique characters
    # then sum the number of times these unique are in special list
    return sum(ch in special for ch in set(password))
```

**Test Code:**

```
test_passwords = (
    ('notspecial', 0),
    ('one_special', 1),
    ('one_special_twice', 1),
    ('two_specials!', 2),
    ('three_specials!?', 3),
    ('three_specials_twice!?!', 3),
)
for pw, count in test_passwords:
    print(pw, count, unique_special_count(pw))
    assert count == unique_special_count(pw)
```

**Results:**

```
notspecial 0 0
one_special 1 1
one_special_twice 1 1
two_specials! 2 2
three_specials!? 3 3
three_specials_twice!?! 3 3
```